# jquery hover does not work in chrome and IE, but works in FF

Tags: jquery

this is  the code I 'm using for hover over the navigation menu items:
Can someone please help me out to find the problem in Chrome and IE

```
$("#unlock_nav a").hover(function () {
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.eileenfisher.com/ns/images/13f_m2/sbi_features/unlocked_season/but_' + $(this).attr('href').slice(1) +'_pink.png');

 },

function(){
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.eileenfisher.com/ns/images/13f_m2/sbi_features/unlocked_season/but_' +  $(this).attr('href').slice(1) + '_white.png');
   });
```

Comment: Hover is working fine in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/FgRRH/

Comment: any console errors in chrome?

Comment: Could you provide link to page, and/or html code? And what slice() method should do, exactly, in your case? You want to remove first character of href attribute?

Comment: the error I have in Chrome dev tool, pointing to jquery...

Comment: <div id="unlock_nav">
<ul> 
  <li id="i1"><a href="#tunic"   class="unlock_ni active" style="width:55px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:0;left:30px;z-index:3;background-image: url(http://www.eileenfisher.com/ns/images/13f_m2/sbi_features/unlocked_season/but_tunic_white.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; cursor:pointer;"></a>
  </li></ul></div>

Comment: The reason I use slice(), I need to remove "#" from <a> name,linking to the tab, so  I could set css link to background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put close bracket in background-image url.

Try this:

```
$("#unlock_nav a").hover(function () {
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.eileenfisher.com/ns/images/13f_m2/sbi_features/unlocked_season/but_' + $(this).attr('href').slice(1) +'_pink.png)');

 },

function(){
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.eileenfisher.com/ns/images/13f_m2/sbi_features/unlocked_season/but_' +  $(this).attr('href').slice(1) + '_white.png)');
   });
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/9nQdm/3/

Comment: Wow, you right. Thank you so much,Unknown. Can not believe I spent 2 days , looking on this...  Great help!!